# ASP.NET Redirecting in a Base Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a base controller which overrides Initialize and sets a cookie and saves some data in the DB. Here I also need to check if a cookie is set and if it is not redirect to an error page.

Users of this site are coming from a store locater on another site which passes the store ID to me and I set it in a cookie. I need to make a sure an ID is stored and if not pass them to an error or back to choose a store.

I am having trouble redirecting or showing this error in the base controller. I even tried the constructor of the controller. Below is code I am trying in Initialize override, but the ControllerContext is null at this point?

```
        if (StoreID == null)
        {
            View("StoreError").ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Very clear explanation from @Darin : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793452/mvc-redirect-inside-the-constructor

Answer (score 6):

the following did the trick...

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/home/storeError");
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to create an Action which will check the Cookie in the OnActionExecuting method and redirect to the proper action method.

Clear Explanation: [MVC - Redirect inside the Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793452/mvc-redirect-inside-the-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

proper way i think would be

```
  Return RedirectToAction("StoreError","Home");
```

no?