# User based authorization in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

Instead of Role based authorization, I need to do the user based authorization.for example I have 10 modules in my project, when I add users I can give permission to users, as which all modules they can access. I can see may tutorials for role based authorization. Is there anything for user based authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple if i have understood your problem correctly

**[AuthorizeAttribute.Users Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.users(v=vs.118).aspx)**

Gets or sets the users that are authorized to access the controller or action method.

Example:

```
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class RestrictedContentController : Controller
{
    . . .
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can we Assign Users dynamially in [Authorize] attribute. If I am adding a new user, he/she has to use my controller. then what to do?

Comment: my pleasure, and simple thing is ,if you see deeply users accepts string with comma separated so you  can assign newly added users to any string variable and give it to the users property .thats it. And if you want  allow all newly added users then simply use [Authorize] attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there isn't something cleary made for that, but with everything else, you can do what you are looking for.

In case you have a business logic or database concept like this one:

Table Modules (Id, Name, ModuleCodeName, etc...)
Table User (Id, Name, etc...)
Table UserAllowedTouseModule (UserId, ModuleId, CreatedOn, ValidFromDateTime, ValidToDateTime, etc...

Several approaches:

Every controller / Area, implements or uses an absctract baseController class, and uses a constructor that receives the ModuleCodeName (value can come from  a string, an enumeration, etc...).
Then you have there a validation or the following type:

- since the user is authenticated, you know its Id, and you can hit the database to verify if he has access to that module (based on the ModuleCodeName received), if not, redirect it to someother place.
- that validation can be made by cached values (instead of going all the time to the database).
- or you can also add those values to a custom authentication property made on the login moment.
- etc.. i think you get the point.

  For this similar logic please have a look on the following question/answer: 
  [MVC - Redirect inside the Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793452/mvc-redirect-inside-the-constructor)