# Make it easier to validate if the same user or not in relation to DRY

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Goal:
Make it easier to validate if the same user or not in relation to DRY.

Problem:
Every time when you go to the next page by using `ActionResult` you have to add a

```
if (Session["UserID"] != null)
```

in every `ActionResult`'s content in order to make a validation.

Question:
Is there another approach in order to make it easier and better than today?

My idea is to use this validation on top of the `ActionResult`

Propose (is it possible to do it?)

```
[validation]
    public ActionResult UserDashBoard()  
    {  
           return View();  
    }
```

And not like this today:

```
    public ActionResult UserDashBoard()  
    {  
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)  
        {  
            return View();  
        } else  
        {  
            return RedirectToAction("Login");  
        }  
    }
```

The source that I am using is from this page.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-login-application-using-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: See related: [How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/)

Comment: As a side note putting the authenticated state in Session is not a good idea. Ideally requests should all be stateless (so Session should not be needed at all) and authentication state should come from the request itself using either a cookie or an http header.

Comment: You could have this validation in the constructor of the controller. if you need a code example let me know.

Comment: Hi Claudio, if possible I am interested in taking part of the this  code example.

Comment: @What'sUP please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793452/mvc-redirect-inside-the-constructor , it is exactly what I use in one of the CRM I have buit

Comment: I couldn't get what "if the same user or not" validation aims?