# ASP.NET CORE Redirect inside the constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, constructor, razor-pages

I am developing a web project using **asp.net core 7** and **razor pages**. I'm dealing with a routing issue. In the Controller, I check whether the user is logged into each method. I think this does not comply with the DRY principle and I try to write clean code as much as I can. I thought about moving this control to the constructor, but I cannot use redirect in the constructor. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793452/mvc-redirect-inside-the-constructor) There is an answer to my similar error here, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Typically you can assign permissions at the controller level, you don't have to at the method level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles

Comment: why dont you just siply use the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution to this problem.

Here I added this to the **Configure** method of the **Startup.cs** file

```
app.UseSession();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string CurrentUserIDSession = context.Session.GetString("userToken");
    if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/User/Login"))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUserIDSession))
        {
            var path = $"/User/Login?ReturnUrl={context.Request.Path}";
            context.Response.Redirect(path);
            return;
        }

    }
    await next();
});
```

Comment: Your question does not match with your answer and what you intended to achieve. It should have read as 'Redirect non-authenticated users to login in ASP.NET Core'...

Comment: The common way to achieve this is to use authentication attributes such as [AllowAnonymous] and [Authorize]. If you need control over them you can implement filters. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters